# Using Folders Within Document Sets in SharePoint 2010

Tags: document-library, folder, document-set

With the New Folder option turned on for a document library that has document sets enabled, the New Folder option is only available on the library itself, not within a Document Set.  When viewing in Windows Explorer a new folder can be created within a Document Set.

Does anyone know of a way to enable the New Folder option on the ribbon within Document Sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like folders aren't offically supported by Microsoft within Document Sets. See the [Document Sets planning (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff603637(v=office.14).aspx)

From the document:

> Folders are not allowed in document sets, and metadata navigation cannot be used in a Document Set

There may be an unsupported way, but it will likely cause problems.

Comment: Do you know a) why and b) if this has changed in Sharepoint 2013?

Answer (score 0):

Yes folders inside document sets are not supported but in share point 2013, it has changed 
https://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/sharepoint-2013-and-folders-in-document-set-why-i-needed-it/